# Microsoft Access equivalent of explain in MySQL

Tags: performance, ms-access

I'm working on a very large query, in a inherited application. This is a large insert-query, that takes 4 tables with well over a million records. I know, I would also rather have this in SQL-server, but there is no infrastructure at this customer to do this :-)

This query has worked for over a year. However, the source-tables keep on growing, and last week it threw the dreaded 'out of system resources'-error. Bummer...!

I think it is possible to optimize this query. Working in MySQL, I would use the explain-command, to see where optimalisation might occur. Is there a equivalent of this in Access? I cannot seem to find it....

kind regards,

Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably Jet ShowPlan is closest to what you want.  You will have to set a registry key.  Then query plan information gets dumped to a text file named SHOWPLAN.OUT.  You can read about the details in this article on TechRepublic: [Use Microsoft Jet's ShowPlan to write more efficient queries](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-microsoft-jets-showplan-to-write-more-efficient-queries/5064388)

Also try the Performance Analyzer wizard.  You can ask it to examine your query alone, or also ask it to examine table or other queries used by that query.

If you haven't compacted the database recently, see whether that improves performance.  Compacting also updates index statistics which allows the engine to make better decisions for the query plan.