# Which is faster: WHERE or HAVING?

Tags: sql, ms-access, where-clause, having

I'm trying to build a query in Microsoft Access and something weird is happening with the WHERE and HAVING clauses. While experimenting with using WHERE and HAVING on a date field (tblDailyFactor.Date) I discovered that including a filter in both the WHERE and HAVING clauses makes the query run significantly faster than simply including the filter in the WHERE clause alone. I used the VBA Timer function to measure the processing time and listed those below along with the two different sets of code.

Can anyone help me to understand why this is happening? I'd like to implement this into my query but I need to be able to explain and justify the code. Thanks!

Run time: 1.01 seconds

```
SELECT tblDailyFactor.Date, tblStaticData1.Name
FROM ((((tblSubTransactions INNER JOIN tblTransactions ON tblSubTransactions.ReferenceNumber = tblTransactions.ReferenceNumber)
    INNER JOIN tblAccounts ON tblTransactions.LocalID = tblAccounts.LocalID)
    INNER JOIN tblStaticData2 ON tblAccounts.LocalID = tblStaticData2.LocalID)
    INNER JOIN tblStaticData1 ON tblStaticData2.GlobalID = tblStaticData1.GlobalID)
    INNER JOIN tblDailyFactor ON tblStaticData1.GlobalID = tblDailyFactor.GlobalID
WHERE (((tblTransactions.Date)<=#8/31/2022#) AND ((tblAccounts.Status)='Active') AND ((tblDailyFactor.Date)=#8/31/2022#))
GROUP BY tblDailyFactor.Date, tblStaticData1.Name
HAVING ((Sum(tblSubTransactions.BalanceUSD))>0.009);
```

Run time: 0.16 seconds

```
SELECT tblDailyFactor.Date, tblStaticData1.Name
FROM ((((tblSubTransactions INNER JOIN tblTransactions ON tblSubTransactions.ReferenceNumber = tblTransactions.ReferenceNumber) 
    INNER JOIN tblAccounts ON tblTransactions.LocalID = tblAccounts.LocalID) 
    INNER JOIN tblStaticData2 ON tblAccounts.LocalID = tblStaticData2.LocalID) 
    INNER JOIN tblStaticData1 ON tblStaticData2.GlobalID = tblStaticData1.GlobalID)
    INNER JOIN tblDailyFactor ON tblStaticData1.GlobalID = tblDailyFactor.GlobalID
WHERE (((tblTransactions.Date)<=#8/31/2022#) AND ((tblAccounts.Status)='Active') AND ((tblDailyFactor.Date)=#8/31/2022#))
GROUP BY tblDailyFactor.Date, tblStaticData1.Name
HAVING (((Sum(tblSubTransactions.BalanceUSD))>0.009) AND ((tblDailyFactor.Date)=#8/31/2022#));
```

(running Microsoft 365 MSO , Version 2110 Build 16.0.14527.20234 64-bit )

Comment: In my book, filtering a selected field must go to the having clause. How does it run if you reduce to: `WHERE (((tblTransactions.Date)<=#8/31/2022#) AND ((tblAccounts.Status)='Active'))`?

Comment: Hi Gustav, I removed the ((tblDailyFactor.Date)=#8/31/2022#) filter from the WHERE clause and the processing time was 0.81 seconds, faster than the query with the date filter in the HAVING clause only but still slower than the query with the date filter in both the WHERE and HAVING clauses.

Comment: @HansUp There seems to be no material difference when run in the opposite order, speed was 0.17 and 0.92 seconds respectively.

Comment: Could have to do with how Jet Database Engine optimizes query execution. Without indexes on columns in `WHERE` clause, including `(tblDailyFactor.Date)=#8/31/2022#` to `HAVING` may result in loading records to memory prior to execution for example. Could try [Jet's Showplan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10100586/4157124) to see what's going on.

Comment: @user4157124 That was a great idea, thanks! I enabled JETSHOWPLAN in the Registry Editor, ran both queries separately and saved each of the files. After looking at the files I can see big differences in execution but I think I'm going to take a little more time to really dive in. Thanks again User 4157124 <3